# Would it be weird in terms of aesthetic to design such a logo?

Tags: drawing, painting, sketching

I'm drawing a sketch for a logo for a noun. Now, the word has 2 adjacent letters in it that can make a thing that describes the noun. But for that I have to put them in vertical order. For example, consider the word Example (Here it reveals nothing but I'm just giving an example):

E X A M P L E becomes

[image]

Comment: In you Example example it is weird. Vertical type is fine. If your logotype is switching from horizontal to vertical type it needs to have a good reason. The car does not have a reason. What is your noun word?

Comment: Whether it'd be weird or not would depend entirely on the logo you draw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *no rules* here.

Conventional reading would tell you *not* to stack glyphs mid-word. But that's for reading. *Reading* a logo is not always the primary goal.

If a logo is designed to contain some visual interest, sacrificing readability can be acceptable at times. This is even more true if the divergence conveys the word more through iconography than typographic glyphs directly.

The word "example" isn't the best use case given stacking the X and A serve as more of a roadblock than a shortcut. Stacking those particular glyphs causes the reader to stop and have to "figure out" what the intention is. But I realize "example" was merely an example. :) But it's these types of road block you should try and avoid.

In many use cases this can work well though. i.e. .... Making the "oo" in "Balloon" look like two stacked balloons.

[image]

While not the optimum configuration for reading, it does a *much better* job of instantly conveying the logotype brand or message.

Even something as simple as....

[image]

Offers a sense of playfulness and recognizability although it breaks traditional reading conventions.

Ultimately whether or not this type of alteration is acceptable comes down to how it's implemented and how it may effect the overall recognizability of the brand. You should never feel constricted by conventional reading structure when designing a logo though. Keep them in mind, but realize it's okay to bend or break rules at times.

Answer (score 3):

Beauty is in the eyes of the beholder.

Weird? Maybe that's the effect you are striving for.

Consider how you felt the first time you saw **Toys "R" Us** with the R flopped and emphasized with quotation and bold colours. Weird? Maybe. Memorable? Most definitely. Mission accomplished.

The idea behind the logotype (logo) is to identify the entity in a unique and distinctive manner to encourage mental stickyness.

That said, if the word "arrangement" can be pronounced and communicated easily and compactly—it's a very practical bonus. For that reason, take the time to arrange the components of the word-mark so as to read correctly as if undistorted.

Your creation need not be a logo which is a commercial application of a design in favour of clever word-play or word-art. Plain fun is a valid goal.